# javascript set variable in a json read function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, variables

I am reading some values from url json API with javascript. I have a combo select, when i choose one option i set the value in a variable and i try to set it to my json read function, is to say, i want dinamically read values from the json. But it not retrieve the data, just print the variable.
 The chain has this aspect

> data.clp.name

i want to change the word "clp" for any of the select combobox.

Here my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
   </head>

<body>

<select id="myselect" onchange="test(this)">
<option value="mxn">Mexico</option>
<option value="eur">España</option>
<option value="cop">Colombia</option>
<option value="clp">Chile</option>
<option value="pen">Peru</option>
</select>

<p id="demo1"></p>


<script>

function test(selectObject){
    var v =   $( "#myselect" ).val();
    var valor = selectObject.value;


    var getJSON1 = function (url, callback) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.responseType = 'json';
        xhr.onload = function () {
            var status = xhr.status;
            if (status === 200) {
                callback(null, xhr.response);
            } else {
                callback(status, xhr.response);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    };

    getJSON1('http://www.floatrates.com/daily/usd.json',
        function (err, data) {
            if (err !== null) {
                alert('Something went wrong: ' + err);
            } else {
                //alert('Your query count: ' + data.moneda.dolar);
                //$("div").append(data.query.lang + " ");
                var t = `data.${valor}.code`

                var text = `Etiqueta: ${t}<br>
                Nombre : ${data.cop.name}<br>
                Dolar : ${data.cop.rate}`                

               // document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = data.valor.name;
                $("#demo1").html(text);
            }
        });    
}
    </script>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the data object using the value of valor, like this: data[valor].  See see the solution below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
   </head>

<body>

<select id="myselect" onchange="test(this)">
<option value="mxn">Mexico</option>
<option value="eur">España</option>
<option value="cop">Colombia</option>
<option value="clp">Chile</option>
<option value="pen">Peru</option>
</select>

<p id="demo1"></p>


<script>

function test(selectObject){
    var v =   $( "#myselect" ).val();
    var valor = selectObject.value;


    var getJSON1 = function (url, callback) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', url, true);
        xhr.responseType = 'json';
        xhr.onload = function () {
            var status = xhr.status;
            if (status === 200) {
                callback(null, xhr.response);
            } else {
                callback(status, xhr.response);
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    };

    getJSON1('https://www.floatrates.com/daily/usd.json',
        function (err, data) {
            if (err !== null) {
                alert('Something went wrong: ' + err);
            } else {
                //alert('Your query count: ' + data.moneda.dolar);
                //$("div").append(data.query.lang + " ");
                var t = data[valor].code

                var text = `Etiqueta: ${t}<br>
                Nombre : ${data[valor].name}<br>
                Dolar : ${data[valor].rate}`                

               // document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = data.valor.name;
                $("#demo1").html(text);
            }
        });    
}
    </script>

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're welcome, please mark the answer correct.  Thanks!